# Avoid picking the same random word in a list until the list is exhausted

Tags: dart

This function picks a random word without repeating a word twice in a row.

How can I improve it so that it doesn't pick the same word until the list is exhausted, i.e. it's gone through the whole list?

```dart
  animateRandomWords() {
    List words = ['changemakers', 'community organizers', 'lovers', 'doers', 'movers and shakers', 'collaborators', 'the crazy ones'];
    var rnd = new Random();
    randomWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];
    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 4), (f) {
      HtmlElement el;
      el = $['random-word'];
      el.style.opacity = '0';
      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 750), () {
        el.style.opacity = '1';
        var newWord;
        do {
          newWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];
        } while (newWord == randomWord);
        randomWord = newWord;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why not just remove a word from the list after you took it?

Comment: Remove the picked words from the initial list, put them in another one. When the initial list is empty, swap it with the other?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, because this keeps looping and so if I remove each word I end up with an empty list of words to pick from. I could repopulate the list at the end, but that seems redundant. I'm wondering what a good approach is.

Comment: I'll try what @Cicada suggests.

Comment: You have to track somehow which word you already took in a list. You can create a copy of the initial list and remove from this copy if you don't want to change the intial list (maybe used as a model for the view).

Comment: Almost there, except once it exhausts the list it stays same length but different order. Hrm. https://gist.github.com/davenotik/4a482272490f387eb0fd

Comment: Bah, can't figure it out. Latest is in the gist. To bed! (Love the inverse schedule. :))

Comment: You could also just shuffle the list, or a copy of the list. Then pick elements in order. That should give a random order, and when you reach the end, you just shuffle the list and start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried other methods as suggested in other answers, and settled on shuffling the list, iterating through it, shuffling again and so on. It's good enough but one thing to note: There still is the chance for repeats, i.e. when the first item in the re-shuffled list matches the last item in the previously shuffled list. Alas, that is a more advanced subject.

```dart
  animateRandomWords() {
    List words = ['changemakers', 'community organizers', 'lovers', 'doers', 'movers and shakers',
      'collaborators', 'the crazy ones', 'makers', 'builders', 'world changers', 'us', 'we vs. me'];
    words.shuffle(new Random());

    var randomWord = words[0]; // Initial random word.
    var i = 1; // Because we already used the first word, start iterating at the second.

    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 4), (f) {
      HtmlElement el;
      el = $['random-word'];
      el.style.opacity = '0';

      new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 750), () {
        el.style.opacity = '1';
        if (i == words.length) {
          i = 0;
        }
        randomWord = words[i];
        print(randomWord);
        i++;
      });
    });
  }
```

I'd love to learn how to improve/simplify this further.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate approach would be to shuffle the list of words then simply iterate through it.

The [Collections package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/collection) implements List shuffle, although I do not know what algorithm it uses, One would hope it is a good implementation of [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).